# trying to crate a regular expression for string

Tags: regex, fme

I have a string like a Taxi:[(h19){h12}], HeavyTruck :[(h19){h12}] wherein I want to keep information before the ":" that is a taxi or heavy truck . can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself?

Comment: Show us how the end result should look like!

Comment: Taxi:[(h19){h12}] in this case i just want taxi .. that is vehicle names and not the hour information. i have tested few things but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will capture a single word if it's followed by `:[` allowing spaces before and after `:`.

```
[A-Za-z]+(?=\s*:\s*\[)
```

You'll need to set regex global flag to capture all occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick in your case: `(?=\s)*\w+(?=\s*:)`

Explanation:

> (?=\s)*  - Searches for 0 or more spaces at the begging of the word without including them in the selection .
>
> \w+  - Selects one or more word characters.
>
> (?=\s*:)  - Searches for 0 or more white spaces after the word followed by a column without including them in the selection.

Answer (score 0):

To match the information in your provided data before the `:` you could try [`[A-Za-z]+(?= ?:)`](https://regex101.com/r/hsYGr5/1) which matches upper or lowercase characters one or more times and uses a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert that what follows is an optional whitespace and a `:`.

If the pattern after the colon should match, your could try: [`[A-Za-z]+(?= ?:\[\(h\d+\){h\d+}])`](https://regex101.com/r/rGS7pX/1)

**Explanation**

- Match one or more upper or lowercase characters `[A-Za-z]+`
- A positive lookahead `(?:` which asserts that what follows
- An optional white space `?`
- Is a colon with the pattern after the colon using `\d+` to match one or more digits (if you want to match a valid time you could update this with a pattern that matches your time format) `:\[\(h\d+\){h\d+}]`
- Close the positive lookahead `)`